# Asp.net Core 6 logout does not work, only redirecting to a page that does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

currently I'm trying to get the logout working in my Asp.Net Core 6 Blazor Server application.

Login is working fine. But logging out redirects to the login url with a redirect to the logout

I call the logout POST the following:
(This is in a .razor file)

```html
<form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut" asp-area="Identity">
    <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Outlined" Color="Color.Info">
        Ausloggen
    </MudButton>
</form>
```

The url that gets called is: **https://localhost:7172/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogOut**

I haven't changed the scaffolded Logout.cshtml file.

I'm registering my Identity like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<WaWiIdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "äabcdefghijklmnöopqrstüuvwxyzÄABCDEFGHIJKLMNÖOPQRSTÜUVWXYZ0123456789ß-._@+/ ";
    })
    .AddRoles<WaWiIdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<WaWiIdentityContext>()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<WaWiIdentityUser>>()
    .AddSignInManager<WaWiSignInManager>()
    .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<WaWiIdentityRole>>();

    builder.Services.AddAuthentication("Identity.Application").AddCookie();
```

The Authentication cookie does not get deleted and the default redirect is not getting called.

This is the default logout I'm using. I tried logging, but the method does not event get called as far as i can tell

```
@functions {
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost()
{
    if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
    {
        await SignInManager.SignOutAsync();
    }

    return Redirect("/");
}
```

}

Do I miss something here?

Thanks ahead for your help.

Comment: _"redirecting to a page that does not exist"_. What page is it redirecting to? What pages _does_ exist? I.e. what page would you like it to redirect to?

Comment: As per your shared `code snippet`,  it seems that the logout path is not correct. If you are using `identity scaffolding` in that case it should like `asp-area="Identity"` and `asp-page="/Account/Logout" ` `asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })"`. You could [`check our official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#log-out) for double check.